# Rename multiple values in file name

Tags: bash, awk, sed, rename

I have a lot of files like these:

```
nsh_nyi.mp4
ott_pit.mp4
chi_wsh.mp4
nyr_mtl.mp4
dal_tbl.mp4
stl_edm.mp4
min_ari.mp4
```

I would like to rename all those files with onliner like so:

```
nsh_nyi.mp4 becomes nashville predators - new york islanders.mp4
ott_pit.mp4 becomes ottawa senators - pittsburgh penguins.mp4
```

Is it possible to with one command in linux, using awk,rename, sed etc?
I tried to bulk rename those files like so:

```
rename s/nsh/nashville\  predators/g
```

It will replace one part of the file, but not the second part: nyi

Of course i have all those club names in one file.
The result is:

```
nsh_nyi.mp4
Can't rename nsh_nyi.mp4 nsh_New-york-islanders.mp4: No such file or directory
ott_pit.mp4
Can't rename ott_pit.mp4 ott_Pittsburgh-penguins.mp4: No such file or directory
```

Comment: 1) a loop for the files 2) split the filename 3) do the translations separately 4) rename 5) good luck - let us know which parts you have difficulties with.

Comment: What does your club names file contents look like? (Show us `head` on that file?)

Comment: Actualli i got it, thanks for helping

Comment: @Jaur: post an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace multiple patterns by listing them all separated by semi-colon as below.

```
rename 's/nsh/nashville\  predators/g;s/ott/ottawa\ senators/g'
```

[Reference](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-sed-substitute-find-replace-multiple-patterns/)

Comment: Is that going to do substitution in the replaced texts as well? I guess so. Test it, and possibly remove/fix your answer.